# properties in objects in parameter for http get method always 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, http-get

I am using .net core 2.0 for this project.

I currently have a simple http get method to search for objects. Since I wanted to add paging for the parameters, I added a paging object.

The problem is that each time I call the method, the paging object has default values (Always 0 for the limit and offset)

I have tried several options, but none of them worked. I'll post my code to show my problem.

The controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("searchByName")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchByName(string searchText, [FromQuery] Paging paging)
{
    // Searching and returning results
}
```

And the paging object looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Paging
{
    public Paging()
    {
    }

    public Paging(int offset, int limit)
    {
        Limit = limit;
        Offset = offset;
    }

    [FromQuery(Name = "Limit")]
    public int Limit { get; }
    [FromQuery(Name = "Offset")]
    public int Offset { get; }
}
```

Each time I call the method with the swagger UI, the limit and offset are always 0.

[image: Example swagger call]

And this is what enters the method when I debug:

[image]

Have I forgot something? I can always change the parameter to two integers, but I would prefer to use objects like shown above. Please let me know if I forgot to add something!

Comment: My first attempt would be to reinstate `set;` for the properties.

Comment: GET requests don't have a body

Comment: @AndyG I'm an idiot... That worked. Will delete question if needed. That was a stupid mistake

Comment: My random guess is/was that it creates an instance of Paging from the data supplied but, because the property-values aren't set in the empty constructor, and aren't settable, they remain as their defaults.

Comment: @AndyG that probably happened. I have stripped all attributes and simple added the `set;` for the properties, and it worked instantly. Should I delete the question or do you want to post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've added an Answer. It was suggested that this was just a typographical error, but I think this sort of issue happens very often, and merits a little explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstate `set;` for the properties.

What happens is that a new instance of Paging is created from the data supplied but, because the property-values aren't set in the empty constructor, and aren't settable, they remain as their default values.